# Kill a process in a Camel route which is blocked

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel, kill, shutdown

How do I kill a process in a route, forcefully?

Consider the follow test class, where a route is defined that has a delay.
The body of the message determines the length of the delay, in this case 3 messages are send, which leads to a delay of 1, 10 and 1 second.
While running, a Timer is looking at the longest inflight messages, and when a message is longer than 2 seconds it should be killed.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.camel.Produce;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.spi.InflightRepository.InflightExchange;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class StopRouteTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StopRouteTest.class);

    @Produce(uri = "direct:start")
    protected ProducerTemplate template;

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        template = context.createProducerTemplate();

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("direct:start")
                .to("direct:b");

                from("direct:b").routeId("testroute")
                .log("a ${body}")
                .delay(simple("${body}"))
                .log("b ${body}");
            }
        });

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Collection<InflightExchange> flights = context.getInflightRepository().browse(10, true);
                for (InflightExchange flight : flights) {
                    LOG.error("This flight is " + flight.getElapsed() + "ms stuck (?) in process " + flight.getNodeId() + " in route " + flight.getRouteId() + ". " + flight.getExchange().toString());
                    if (flight.getElapsed() > 2000) {
                        try {
                        context.stopRoute("testroute", 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, false);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 500, 500);

        context.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testRoute() throws InterruptedException {
        template.sendBody("direct:start", 1000);
        template.sendBody("direct:start", 10000);

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        template.sendBody("direct:start", 1000);
    }
}
```

The route will receive a stopping call, but will keep running until the delay is stopped:

```
2015-12-15 16:02:08,472 | INFO  | aultCamelContext | Apache Camel 2.15.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
2015-12-15 16:02:08,472 | INFO  | nagementStrategy | JMX is enabled
2015-12-15 16:02:09,036 | INFO  | ultTypeConverter | Loaded 195 type converters
2015-12-15 16:02:09,239 | INFO  | aultCamelContext | AllowUseOriginalMessage is enabled. If access to the original message is not needed, then its recommended to turn this option off as it may improve performance.
2015-12-15 16:02:09,239 | INFO  | aultCamelContext | StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
2015-12-15 16:02:09,317 | INFO  | aultCamelContext | Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://start]
2015-12-15 16:02:09,317 | INFO  | aultCamelContext | Route: testroute started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://b]
2015-12-15 16:02:09,317 | INFO  | aultCamelContext | Total 2 routes, of which 2 is started.
2015-12-15 16:02:09,317 | INFO  | aultCamelContext | Apache Camel 2.15.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.845 seconds
2015-12-15 16:02:09,348 | INFO  | testroute        | a 1000
2015-12-15 16:02:09,489 | ERROR | StopRouteTest    | This flight is 141ms stuck (?) in process delay1 in route testroute. Exchange[Message: 1000]
2015-12-15 16:02:10,004 | ERROR | StopRouteTest    | This flight is 656ms stuck (?) in process delay1 in route testroute. Exchange[Message: 1000]
2015-12-15 16:02:10,363 | INFO  | testroute        | b 1000
2015-12-15 16:02:10,363 | INFO  | testroute        | a 10000
2015-12-15 16:02:10,504 | ERROR | StopRouteTest    | This flight is 141ms stuck (?) in process delay1 in route testroute. Exchange[Message: 10000]
2015-12-15 16:02:11,019 | ERROR | StopRouteTest    | This flight is 656ms stuck (?) in process delay1 in route testroute. Exchange[Message: 10000]
2015-12-15 16:02:11,519 | ERROR | StopRouteTest    | This flight is 1156ms stuck (?) in process delay1 in route testroute. Exchange[Message: 10000]
2015-12-15 16:02:12,019 | ERROR | StopRouteTest    | This flight is 1656ms stuck (?) in process delay1 in route testroute. Exchange[Message: 10000]
2015-12-15 16:02:12,534 | ERROR | StopRouteTest    | This flight is 2171ms stuck (?) in process delay1 in route testroute. Exchange[Message: 10000]
2015-12-15 16:02:12,534 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 1 seconds)
2015-12-15 16:02:12,535 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 1 seconds.
2015-12-15 16:02:13,549 | WARN  | ShutdownStrategy | Timeout occurred during graceful shutdown. Forcing the routes to be shutdown now. Notice: some resources may still be running as graceful shutdown did not complete successfully.
2015-12-15 16:02:13,549 | WARN  | ShutdownStrategy | Interrupted while waiting during graceful shutdown, will force shutdown now.
2015-12-15 16:02:13,549 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Route: testroute shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://b]
2015-12-15 16:02:13,549 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 1 seconds
2015-12-15 16:02:13,549 | INFO  | aultCamelContext | Route: testroute is stopped, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://b]
2015-12-15 16:02:13,549 | ERROR | StopRouteTest    | This flight is 3186ms stuck (?) in process delay1 in route testroute. Exchange[Message: 10000]
2015-12-15 16:02:13,549 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 1 seconds)
2015-12-15 16:02:13,549 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 1 seconds.
2015-12-15 16:02:14,564 | WARN  | ShutdownStrategy | Timeout occurred during graceful shutdown. Forcing the routes to be shutdown now. Notice: some resources may still be running as graceful shutdown did not complete successfully.
2015-12-15 16:02:14,564 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 1 seconds
2015-12-15 16:02:14,564 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Route: testroute shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://b]
2015-12-15 16:02:14,564 | INFO  | aultCamelContext | Route: testroute is stopped, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://b]
2015-12-15 16:02:14,564 | ERROR | StopRouteTest    | This flight is 4201ms stuck (?) in process delay1 in route testroute. Exchange[Message: 10000]
2015-12-15 16:02:14,564 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 1 seconds)
2015-12-15 16:02:14,564 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 1 seconds.
2015-12-15 16:02:15,564 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 0 seconds.
2015-12-15 16:02:15,580 | WARN  | ShutdownStrategy | Interrupted while waiting during graceful shutdown, will force shutdown now.
2015-12-15 16:02:15,580 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Route: testroute shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://b]
2015-12-15 16:02:15,580 | WARN  | ShutdownStrategy | Timeout occurred during graceful shutdown. Forcing the routes to be shutdown now. Notice: some resources may still be running as graceful shutdown did not complete successfully.
2015-12-15 16:02:15,580 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 1 seconds
2015-12-15 16:02:15,580 | INFO  | aultCamelContext | Route: testroute is stopped, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://b]
2015-12-15 16:02:15,580 | ERROR | StopRouteTest    | This flight is 5217ms stuck (?) in process delay1 in route testroute. Exchange[Message: 10000]
2015-12-15 16:02:15,580 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 1 seconds)
2015-12-15 16:02:15,580 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 1 seconds.
2015-12-15 16:02:16,581 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 0 seconds.
2015-12-15 16:02:16,582 | WARN  | ShutdownStrategy | Timeout occurred during graceful shutdown. Forcing the routes to be shutdown now. Notice: some resources may still be running as graceful shutdown did not complete successfully.
2015-12-15 16:02:16,582 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 1 seconds
2015-12-15 16:02:16,582 | WARN  | ShutdownStrategy | Interrupted while waiting during graceful shutdown, will force shutdown now.
2015-12-15 16:02:16,582 | INFO  | aultCamelContext | Route: testroute is stopped, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://b]
2015-12-15 16:02:16,582 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Route: testroute shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://b]
2015-12-15 16:02:16,582 | ERROR | StopRouteTest    | This flight is 6219ms stuck (?) in process delay1 in route testroute. Exchange[Message: 10000]
2015-12-15 16:02:16,582 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 1 seconds)
2015-12-15 16:02:16,582 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 1 seconds.
2015-12-15 16:02:17,612 | WARN  | ShutdownStrategy | Timeout occurred during graceful shutdown. Forcing the routes to be shutdown now. Notice: some resources may still be running as graceful shutdown did not complete successfully.
2015-12-15 16:02:17,612 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 1 seconds
2015-12-15 16:02:17,612 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Route: testroute shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://b]
2015-12-15 16:02:17,612 | INFO  | aultCamelContext | Route: testroute is stopped, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://b]
2015-12-15 16:02:17,612 | ERROR | StopRouteTest    | This flight is 7249ms stuck (?) in process delay1 in route testroute. Exchange[Message: 10000]
2015-12-15 16:02:17,612 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 1 seconds)
2015-12-15 16:02:17,612 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 1 seconds.
2015-12-15 16:02:18,627 | WARN  | ShutdownStrategy | Timeout occurred during graceful shutdown. Forcing the routes to be shutdown now. Notice: some resources may still be running as graceful shutdown did not complete successfully.
2015-12-15 16:02:18,627 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 0 seconds.
2015-12-15 16:02:18,627 | WARN  | ShutdownStrategy | Interrupted while waiting during graceful shutdown, will force shutdown now.
2015-12-15 16:02:18,627 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Route: testroute shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://b]
2015-12-15 16:02:18,627 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 1 seconds
2015-12-15 16:02:18,627 | INFO  | aultCamelContext | Route: testroute is stopped, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://b]
2015-12-15 16:02:18,627 | ERROR | StopRouteTest    | This flight is 8264ms stuck (?) in process delay1 in route testroute. Exchange[Message: 10000]
2015-12-15 16:02:18,627 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 1 seconds)
2015-12-15 16:02:18,627 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 1 seconds.
2015-12-15 16:02:19,627 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 0 seconds.
2015-12-15 16:02:19,643 | WARN  | ShutdownStrategy | Timeout occurred during graceful shutdown. Forcing the routes to be shutdown now. Notice: some resources may still be running as graceful shutdown did not complete successfully.
2015-12-15 16:02:19,643 | WARN  | ShutdownStrategy | Interrupted while waiting during graceful shutdown, will force shutdown now.
2015-12-15 16:02:19,643 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 1 seconds
2015-12-15 16:02:19,643 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Route: testroute shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://b]
2015-12-15 16:02:19,643 | INFO  | aultCamelContext | Route: testroute is stopped, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://b]
2015-12-15 16:02:19,643 | ERROR | StopRouteTest    | This flight is 9280ms stuck (?) in process delay1 in route testroute. Exchange[Message: 10000]
2015-12-15 16:02:19,643 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 1 seconds)
2015-12-15 16:02:19,643 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 1 seconds.
2015-12-15 16:02:20,363 | INFO  | route1           | stopped a route...
2015-12-15 16:02:20,644 | WARN  | ShutdownStrategy | Timeout occurred during graceful shutdown. Forcing the routes to be shutdown now. Notice: some resources may still be running as graceful shutdown did not complete successfully.
2015-12-15 16:02:20,644 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 1 seconds
2015-12-15 16:02:20,644 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Route: testroute shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://b]
2015-12-15 16:02:20,644 | INFO  | aultCamelContext | Route: testroute is stopped, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://b]
2015-12-15 16:02:22,379 | ERROR | aultErrorHandler | Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-ITRDW7P059-51472-1450191728066-0-5 on ExchangeId: ID-ITRDW7P059-51472-1450191728066-0-6). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://b]. Exchange[Message: 1000]

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [direct://start                                                                ] [         0]
[route1            ] [to1               ] [direct:b                                                                      ] [         0]

Exchange
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exchange[
    Id                  ID-ITRDW7P059-51472-1450191728066-0-6
    ExchangePattern     InOnly
    Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID-ITRDW7P059-51472-1450191728066-0-5, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0}
    BodyType            Integer
    Body                1000
]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://b]. Exchange[Message: 1000]
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:47)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:51)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProducer.process(UnitOfWorkProducer.java:68)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:375)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:343)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:233)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:343)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:184)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:124)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:137)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:144)
    at nl.test.StopRouteTest.testRoute(StopRouteTest.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
2015-12-15 16:02:22,519 | INFO  | StopRouteTest    | ********************************************************************************
2015-12-15 16:02:22,519 | INFO  | StopRouteTest    | Testing done: testRoute(nl.test.StopRouteTest)
2015-12-15 16:02:22,519 | INFO  | StopRouteTest    | Took: 14.546 seconds (14546 millis)
2015-12-15 16:02:22,519 | INFO  | StopRouteTest    | ********************************************************************************
2015-12-15 16:02:22,519 | INFO  | aultCamelContext | Apache Camel 2.15.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
2015-12-15 16:02:22,519 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Starting to graceful shutdown 2 routes (timeout 1 seconds)
2015-12-15 16:02:22,519 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Route: testroute shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://b]
2015-12-15 16:02:22,519 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Route: route1 shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://start]
2015-12-15 16:02:22,614 | INFO  | ShutdownStrategy | Graceful shutdown of 2 routes completed in 0 seconds
2015-12-15 16:02:22,629 | INFO  | aultCamelContext | Apache Camel 2.15.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) uptime 14.157 seconds
2015-12-15 16:02:22,629 | INFO  | aultCamelContext | Apache Camel 2.15.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutdown in 0.110 seconds
```

How would I be able to stop the process?
As you can see, at 2015-12-15 16:02:10,363 the 10 second delay message is starting, after about 2 seconds the route is 'killed' and precisely 10 seconds later the route is actually stopped.
So not a real stop, but just waiting until the process is done.

Btw, this is off course not the real use-case, that has something to do with a database, but I assume it should be solved in a similar way, due to the layout of the code.

Comment: exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE); seems to be the way to stop an exchange from going further

Answer (score 0):

Killing threads in Java is not easy, its not like killing processes on the OS level.

It is a bad smell if you try to do something like that as part of normal business operation.

Only if a rouge thread that is stuck somehow, it can be advised to try to kill / terminate it.

What you can do is to mark the exchange to stop routing, see the source code of StopProcessor how it does that. From the inflight repository you can get hold of the exchange of that route, and mark it to stop.